# How to speed up insertion into Redis from SQL Query using Python

Tags: python, redis

I have a SQL query I execute, and it comes into my Python program ~500ms (about 100k rows).

I want to quickly insert this into redis, but it currently takes ~6sec, even with piping.

```
pipe = r.pipeline()
for row in q:
    pipe.zincrby(SKEY, row["name"], 1)
pipe.execute()
```

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: So what is the question you are asking? Consider editing post adding the actual question such as "how to speed up inserts into redis?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you insert a large number of items in a sorted set. Redis doc says that the time complexity of zincrby is O(log(N)) where N is the number of elements in the sorted set. So the more items you insert, the longer it takes. You probably should rethink the way you use Redis in this case. Maybe the sorted set is not the best answer to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

In general there's no way to speed this up from redis's perspective, but there are two things you can do:

1 If keys repeat themselves, try reducing the number of rows by summing up the names before calling redis. i.e.:

```
d = dict()
for row in q:
   name = row["name"]
   d[name] = d.get(name, 0) + 1
```

and then if you have recurring ids, you'll make less queries in redis.

2 Another thing I would try it to call execute() every say 1000 or 5000 commands or so, that way redis would not be blocking for other callers while this is executed, and python itself would allocate less memory, which might speed things up.

e.g. (combined with the above):

```
d = dict()
for row in q:
   name = row["name"]
   d[name] = d.get(name, 0) + 1

pipe = r.pipeline()
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.iteritems()):
    pipe.zincrby(SKEY, k, v)
    if i > 0 and i % 5000 == 0:
        pipe.execute()

pipe.execute()
```